# Postgresql terminal throws illegal array element error when trying to type JSON

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a recursive JSON equality operator. Right now the trouble is that for some reason when I type out a JSON literal in a PL-PGSQL anonymous block for testing, it constantly throws an illegal array element syntax error.

Below is my current code.

```
DO $$
    DECLARE
        keys1 text[];
        keys2 text[];
        json1 json;
    BEGIN
        json1 := '{"a5":16,"b2":14}'::json;
        SELECT * FROM json_object_keys(json1) into keys1;
    END
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `into` clause of the `select` statement. `json_object_keys()` returns a *set* of text, that is a resultset made of 1 column and 0 to N rows. You cannot assign it to a variable declared as an array of text

One workaround to make the assignment possible without changing the type of the target variable is to use `array_agg()`:

```
select array_agg(k) into keys1 from json_object_keys(json1) as x(k);
```